# Windows server backup skips itself

Tags: backup, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-backup

There is a Windows Server 2012 R2 with a scheduled windows server backup, but it does not run the backup. However, if I hit the "Run Once" backup, it runs successfully. There is no log at %windir%\logs\windowsserverbackup

In the Event Viewer there is no error event, apart from the following ones:

> The WMI Performance Adapter service entered the stopped state.
>   The Block Level Backup Engine Service service entered the running state.
>   The Volume Shadow Copy service entered the running state.
>   The Microsoft Software Shadow Copy Provider service entered the running 
>   state.
>   The Volume Shadow Copy service entered the stopped state.

And that's all.

Any idea?